# inetsvr's appcmd emits error after issued

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, wcf, command-line

> ERROR ( message:New binding object missing required attributes. Cannot
>   add dupli cate collection entry of type 'binding' with combined key
>   attributes 'protocol, bindingInformation' respectively set to
>   'net.tcp, 808:*'

That is the error I run into while trying to run

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[p
rotocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']
```

I don't know why and would love to hear your ideas and follow your guidance,

Thank you a lot for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead 
`appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']`

That is try to type the command in single line.

Guess You may already installed the command.You verify with the default website bindings,It should be already addedd.

Thanks

Deepak